# How to find non-ascii characters in file using Regular Expression Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

I have a string of characters that includes [a-z] as well as á,ü,ó,ñ,å,... and so on. Currently I am using regular expressions to get every line in a file that includes these characters.

Sample of spanishList.txt:

```
adan
celular
tomás
justo
tom
átomo
camara
rosa
avion
```

Python code (`charactersToSearch` comes from flask `@application.route('/<charactersToSearch>')`):

```
print (charactersToSearch)
#'átdsmjfnueó'
...
#encode
charactersToSearch = charactersToSearch.encode('utf-8')
query = re.compile('[' + charactersToSearch + ']{2,}$', re.UNICODE).match
words = set(word.rstrip('\n') for word in open('spanishList.txt') if query(word))
...
```

When I do this, I am expecting to get the words in the text file that include the characters in `charactersToSearch`. It works perfectly for words without special characters:

```
...
#after doing further searching for other conditions, return list of found words.
return '<br />'.join(sorted(set(word for (word, path) in solve())))
>>> adan
>>> justo
>>> tom
```

Only problem is that it ignores all words in the file that aren't ASCII. I should also be getting `tomás` and `átomo`.

I've tried encode, UTF-8, using ur'[...], but I haven't been able to get it to work for all characters. The file and the program (`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`) are in utf-8 as well.

Comment: have you tried `query = re.compile(u'[' + charactersToSearch + ']{2,}$', re.UNICODE).match` and not encoding `charactersToSearch` to utf8?, but instead just leave it as unicode?

Comment: For clarification, are you considering `á` to be non-ASCII? It's dec 225 in the extended table. (But can also be represented as `a` + acute accent)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes. I've tried both ways but every time I get the list of words without any special characters included.

Comment: @zx81 I'm not sure how to respond. How do I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The was able to figure out the issue. After getting the string from the flask app route, encode it otherwise it give you an error, and then decode the `charactersToSearch` and each `word` in the file.

```
charactersToSearch = charactersToSearch.encode('utf-8')
```

Then decode it in UTF-8. If you leave the previous line out it give you an error

```
UNIOnlyAlphabet = charactersToSearch.decode('UTF-8')
query = re.compile('[' + UNIOnlyAlphabet + ']{2,}$', re.U).match
```

Lastly, when reading the UTF-8 file and using query, don't forget to decode each word in the file.

```
words = set(word.decode('UTF-8').rstrip('\n') for word in open('spanishList.txt') if query(word.decode('UTF-8')))
```

That should do it. Now the results show regular and special characters.

```
justo
tomás
átomo
adan
tom
```

Answer (score 0):

**A different tack**

I'm not sure how to fix it in your current workflow, so I'll suggest a different route.

This regex will match characters that are neither white-space characters nor letters in the extended ASCII range, such as `A` and `é`. In other words, if one of your words contains a weird character that is not part of this set, the regex will match.

```
(?i)(?!(?![×Þß÷þø])[a-zÀ-ÿ])\S
```

Of course this will also match punctuation, but I'm assuming that we're only looking at words in an unpunctuated list. otherwise, excluding punctuation is not too hard.

As I see it, your challenge is to define your set.

In Python, you can so something like:

```
if re.search(r"(?i)(?!(?![×Þß÷þø])[a-zÀ-ÿ])\S", subject):
    # Successful match
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain. Dealing with Unicode in python2.x is the headache.

The problem with that input is that python sees "á" as the raw byte string '\xc3\xa1' instead of the unicode character "u'\uc3a1'. So your going to need to sanitize the input before passing the string into your regex.

To change a raw byte string to to a unicode string

```
char = "á"
## print char yields the infamous, and in python unparsable "\xc3\xa1".
## which is probably what the regex is not registering.
bytes_in_string = [byte for byte in char]
string = ''.join([str(hex(ord(byte))).strip('0x') for byte in bytes_in_string])
new_unicode_string = unichr(int(string),16))
```

There's probably a better way, because this is a lot of operations to get something ready for regex, which I think is supposed to be faster in some way than iterating & 'if/else'ing.
Dunno though, not an expert.

I used something similar to this to isolate the special char words when I parsed wiktionary which was a wicked mess. As far as I can tell your going to have to comb through that to clean it up anyways, you may as well just:

```
for word in file:
    try:
        word.encode('UTF-8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        your_list_of_special_char_words.append(word)
```

Hope this helped, and good luck!

On further research found this post:

[Bytes in a unicode Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845842/bytes-in-a-unicode-python-string)

Comment: So when I try to change from a raw byte string to unicode I get an error. Assuming the input text of `áaceimsonñpórxül`, `bytes_in_string` gives me: `['\xc3', '\xa1', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'm', 's', 'o', 'n', '\xc3', '\xb1', 'p', '\xc3', '\xb3', 'r', 'x', '\xc3', '\xbc', 'l']` and then string prints `c3a1616365696d736f6ec3b17c3b37278c3bc6c`. Now I can see that for example, á is made up of \xc3 & \xa1. When I run `new_unicode_string`, the error I get says: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'c3a1616365696d736f6ec3b17c3b37278c3bc6c'`...as it's not just numbers. Any suggestions.?

Comment: I was able to fix the issue: