# Identify code points above U+10FFFF

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I'm working on a program where I should reject any code point above U+10FFFF.  This seems straightforward enough, except I can't figure out how to represent such a range of code points in my regular expression.  I want to do something like this

```
valid_character = re.compile(u'[\u0000-\u10FFFF]')
```

and then have anything that doesn't match that be handled appropriately.  However, `\u` only seems to recognize the first four characters, namely `10FF`.  Is there another way to represent this code point range or handle this situation?

[This site](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10ffff/index.htm) recommends `u"\U0010FFFF"` but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
>>> ord(u'\U0010FFFF')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
```

Comment: What does your input look like? Python should, by definition, reject any Unicode "character" above U+10ffff, since they do not exist.

Comment: @chepner I'll be getting some input file and (among other things) I have to strip out characters that do not fall in this range

Comment: It can't be specified with the `\u` or `\U` syntax, since characters above `U+10FFFF` are not valid Unicode.  What is the encoding of your file?  Provide a sample with the characters you need to filter.

Comment: Isn't it possible to synthesize a character code that is technically valid but not valid for (the current version of) Unicode?

Comment: @MarkTolonen unfortunately I don't have a good sample of a file; this is just part of a preprocessing routine I was asked to write and I was told that it was required.  As far as I know there is no reason for us to expect such an input or any encoding besides UTF-8.  That is sort of why I'm asking - it seems nonsensical to me.  If it truly is nonsensical then I'm fine with going back to my boss with that.

Comment: @Jongware, it's possible to create, say, a 5- or 6-byte UTF-8-like encoded character manually, just not with Python's `\U` syntax.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: got it -- so Python itself guards against that. So, by extension, you cannot use Python string functions to check for a value *outside* of it? Can an externally loaded text string *also* not contain invalid Unicode? (Which implies Python would clean input before converting it to a string object -- correct?)

Comment: The original [UTF-8 design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) allows for 5- and 6-byte UTF-8 encodings so it is possible for someone to generate a file with illegal Unicode characters encoded that way.

Comment: Apologies for asking the above clarification, as it veers off the topic of the question: "why can't OP use the *correct* way for Unicode characters?"

Comment: If you decode a file with UTF-8 that violates the spec, Python will throw an error, so the answer to your question is "just open the file and decode it as UTF-8".  Python will handle it if the characters are invalid.

Comment: Cool, that's all I wanted to know.  Feel free to answer the question with that and I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: There are no Unicode characters and no Unicode code points beyond U+10FFFF, according to the definitions of the Unicode standard. You should rewrite the question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela better?

Comment: As I wrote, there are Unicode code points either beyond U+10FFFF. You should describe the data you are actually dealing with, instead of calling it Unicode code points or characters when it cannot be that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you decode a file with UTF-8 that violates the spec, Python will throw an error, so the answer to your question is "just open the file and decode it as UTF-8". Python will handle it if the characters are invalid.

Example:

```
>>> b'\xf4\x8f\xbf\xbf'.decode('utf8')
u'\U0010ffff'

# UTF-8 equivalent to \U00110000...
>>> len(b'\xf4\x90\x80\x80'.decode('utf8'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\dev\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-2: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: This solves the OP's X-Y problem, so good call on that ... but it left me wondering how to construct OP's regex.

Comment: @Jongware, maybe something like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9848242/235698).  It finds valid UTF-8 sequences.